Martingale inequality with Convex Function
I want to know how to prove following equation appearing in the book 'Stochastic approximation and recursive algorithms and applications' without proof.
Let $\{Mn,Fn\}$ be a martingale, $q(\cdot)$ be a non-negative non-decreasing convex function. Then for any integers $n < N$ and $\lambda > 0$
\begin{aligned}
P_{\mathscr F_n}\left\{\underset{n\leq m\leq N}{\sup}|M_m|\geq\lambda\right\}\leq \frac{E_{\mathscr F_n}[q(M_N)]}{q(\lambda)}
\end{aligned}

I think you'll need to have $E_{\mathcal{F}{n}}(q(|M{N}|))$ . Otherwise take $M_{n}=-\lambda$ to be the constant sequence. Then obviously it's martingale. Take $q(x)$ to be $0$ when $x\leq 0$ and $x^{2}$ when $x>0$. Then you have that the left hand side is identically $1$. But the right hand side is $0$ as $q(M_{N})=0$.

A proof for the case where $q$ is of the form $q(x) = |x|^p$, $p\geq 1$, you can find in e.g. the book by Ikeda and Watanabe, p. 28. Maybe it allows generalisation to your case.

@Mr.Gandalf Sauron sensei. Thank you, you're right. That's so cool to be able to spot an error in the textbook with a counterexample. I didn't notice.

@Bart Thank you for the information. That's very helpful.

@出木杉英才 The thing is that if you wanted $\displaystyle P_{\mathcal{F}{n}}(\sup{n\leq m\leq N}M_{m}\geq \lambda)$ then you'll get the bound $\displaystyle\frac{1}{q(\lambda)}\cdot E_{\mathcal{F}{n}}(q(M{N}))$ by employing the same technique in my answer and noting that $q(M_{n})$ is a submartingale.

Define $T=\inf\{k\geq n: |M_{k}|\geq\lambda\}\wedge N$.
Then $T$ is a bounded stopping time and $T\leq N$
Now note that $\{\sup_{n\leq m\leq N}|M_{k}|\geq\lambda\}=\{|M_{T}|\geq \lambda\}=\{q(|M_{T}|)\geq q(\lambda)\}$.
This gives you that $$P(\{\sup_{n\leq m\leq N}|M_{k}|\geq\lambda\}|\mathcal{F_{n}})=P(q(|M_{T}|)\geq q(\lambda)|\mathcal{F}_{n})\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_{n}}(q(|M_{T}|))}{q(\lambda)}$$
Now just note that $q(|M_{n}|)$ is a submartingale due to Jensen's Inequality.
Thus, the Optional Sampling Theorem gives you that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_{n}}(q(|M_{T}|))\leq \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_{n}}(q(|M_{N}|))$
Thus $$P\{\sup_{n\leq m\leq N}|M_{k}|>\lambda|\mathcal{F}_{n}\}\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_{n}}(q(|M_{N}|))}{q(\lambda)}$$

@出木杉英才 You can mark as answer then.
